# Google Analytics Event Tracking doesn't track twice or more

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, event-tracking

I am trying to track an event via Google Analytics but unfortunately it only works for the first time I click the element. When I change the browser it only works the first time again.
I use this simple code to track:

`ga('send', 'event', 'footer', category , label, 1);`

`category` and `label` are JS variables

Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help you if you install Chrome extension GA Debugger (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en). Activate it and watch in the DevTools Console panel what happens when you click the target. It reports what was really sent to Google Analytics with the beacon. For example I have:

```
ga( "send", "event", "Videos", "play", "Fall Campaign", 1 );
```

which is called when user click the link. Every time I click the link I get in the console a new payload like:

```
Running command: ga("send", "event", "Videos", "play", "Fall Campaign", 1)
Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j79d&aip=1&a=1635498924&t=event..
```

I keep also open https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/ on Realtime/Events/Events (Last 30 min) and observer every time a new event registered.

P.S. Just to avoid the case where some events not being really delivered to Google Analytics, let's say after code update, I have automated tests set like described here https://docs.puppetry.app/testing-techniques/testing-google-analytics-tracking-code

Comment: i installed the extension and it responds every time i click the link but on Realtime/Events/Events it still stays 1. If another user would click the link it would increase but if the same user clicks it more than once the value wouldn't increase

Comment: The tab is "Events (Last 30 min)", right? Because the default one is "Active Users", which  apparently shows the last event per user...

Comment: If it helps here the source code of working example https://github.com/dsheiko/puppetry/blob/master/project-test/gat.html

Comment: It was the default one "Active Users". When I select the "Events (Last 30 min)" tab it displays the right number.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if this work
   target="_blank" to the link to crosscheck the event.
2. Also, verify if ur using analytics.js or gtag.js tracking code snippet.
3. link it in double quote
   href="http://mywebpage.com"

Comment: I'm using analytics.js and the element i'm clicking has target="_blank" and double quotes but it doesn't work either for elements that do not have the target attribute